# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Discrete Uniform random variables on {-1,1}. What is the distribution of $X + Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Discrete Uniform random variables on
>   {-1,1}. What is the distribution of $X + Y$? Give its PMF.

The way I approached this question is by noting that $X$ and $Y$ are independent discrete so that would mean that $X$ and $Y$ can only take on values, $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability.

So the distribution of $X,Y$ would be,

$$X,Y =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \frac{1}{2} \\
-1, & \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$$

with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

For the distribution of $X + Y$ I looked at all the possible values that it can take on and came up with this:

$(0, 2, -2); 0=1+(-1), 2=1+1, -2=-1+(-1)$

So the distribution of $X + Y$ would be:

$$X+Y =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \frac{1}{4} \\
0, & \frac{1}{4} \\
-2, & \frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}$$

The way I came up with $\frac{1}{4}$ is because $X$, $Y$ are independent, so for values $2,0,-2$ the probability would be:

$2 (X=1,Y=1) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$, 
$-2 (X=-1,Y=-1) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$,
$0 (X=1,Y=-1) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

Therefore, the PMF would be: $$f_{X+Y}(x) = \frac{1}{4}; x = 0,2,-2$$

Is this the correct way to approach this question and is my solution to this problem correct? Thank you to anyone that helps.

Comment: The general approach is fine. But $\Pr(X+Y=0)=1/2$.  For the sum can be $0$ in two ways.

Comment: I would draw a $2\times 2$ table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a slight error in not recognizing that $X+Y$ can be $0$ in 2 ways: $(X,Y)=(-1,+1)$ and $(X,Y)=(+1,-1)$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ each. An easy way to realize that an error has been committed is checking whether your various probabilities for $X+Y$ sum to $1$.

I also find your solution wordy so I present an alternative write up below. Of course, this is subjective.

---

Because of independence, the joint probability mass function of $(X,Y)$ can be described as follows:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
& \hline X=+1 & X=-1  \\\hline
Y=+1 &  1/4  & 1/4 \\\hline
Y=-1 &  1/4  & 1/4 \\\hline
\end{array}
Correspondingly, $X+Y$ takes on 3 different values $\{2,0,-2\}$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}$, respectively.